# Getting sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError when trying to setup an one to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables that I`m trying to setup with this relationship but when I try to run the app i get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to
> initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.

```
class Items(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Item'

    ID_ITEM = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    NAME = Column(String(80, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'), nullable=False)

    addresses = relationship('Unit', backref='items', lazy=True)
```

```
class Unit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Units'

    ID_UNIT = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    VALUE = Column(Numeric(12, 2), nullable=False)

    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), nullable=False)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it the case of 'item.id' in the line `item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), nullable=False)`  You hard coded the table name of Items as `Item`

Comment: So im supposed to change the name of the table?

Comment: try changing the identifier of your ForeignKey to `'Item.ID_ITEM'`.  The foreign key is looking for `table_name.column_name`

Comment: Didn`t work, it keeps saying it failed to locate a name ('Unit) but I dont know what to do to make it find the class.

Comment: I don't get the same error as you do. With [this code](https://pastebin.com/ZM4AWAY1) I get "sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'Units.item_id' could not find table 'item' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'"

Comment: … but when I change `ForeignKey('item.id')` to `ForeignKey("Item.ID_ITEM")` it seems to work fine.

Comment: Do i have to put both models on the same file so that the relationship can find the Unit class?

Comment: You'll probably need to `import` a model if it is in a different file.

Comment: Yes it worked now, thank you.